# Did plankton inspire Giger's design for Alien

Tags: aliens, inspiration, design

I was recently reminded that during David Attenborough's series The Blue Planet, Attenborough makes a claim that one particular form of plankton inspired the design of Giger's alien as seen in the Ridley Scott film. Most information on Giger's alien design state that it was developed from an already completed painting called Necronom IV. The plankton in question is called Phronima and does look somewhat similar to the design of Giger's alien

This article

https://arthropoda.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/did-phronima-inspire-the-design-of-the-alien-queen/

discusses the idea that Phronima actually influenced the design of the alien queen from James Cameron's Aliens and this may be what Attenborough was incorrectly referring to. The writer of the article mentions attempting to contact Stan Winston's special effects company for clarification but was not successful in getting an answer.

My question is, can anyone find a quote or comment from Giger, Ridley Scott, James Cameron, Stan Winston or even someone who worked on design of Alien or Aliens to clarify if a particular type of plankton influenced the design of the alien or the alien queen?

Comment: Lol. I'm pretty sure that Giger's inspiration was primarily female genitalia

Comment: @Valorum Not just female—there are a lot of penis allusions present as well.

Comment: @Buzz - a few years ago I came to the conclusion that if you could somehow get a job as Giger's psychotherapist, you would be set for life.

Comment: Take a look at the second jaw of Moray eel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbLgE7pMMkA